# How Can I Destructure error from is RTK Query Mutation Hook?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rtk-query

I am using redux toolkit query for my data fetching API.
The problem is I am having is error handling redux toolkit returns an error property from the query hook. So the error that is returned from the server is an object with nested data and what trying to access it I get a typescript error when trying to access the data from the error object.

below is how I am declaring my mutation hook

```js
const [updateProgram, {
  isLoading: isUpdatingProgram,
  error: updateProgramError
}] = useUpdateProgramMutation();
```

below is how I try to access the error in my code.

```js
onSubmit = {
  async(values, {
    setSubmitting
  }) => {
    await updateProgram({ ...values,
      id: 'programData.data._id'
    });
    refetch();

    if (updateProgramError) {
      enqueueSnackbar('Test message', {
        variant: 'error'
      });
      console.log(updateProgramError?.data?.message);
    }
    setSubmitting(false);
  }
}
```

now the typescript error I am getting is as below.
Not that I able to console.log(updateProgramError) and is the data in the console

```js
Property 'data' does not exist on type 'FetchBaseQueryError | SerializedError'.
  Property 'data' does not exist on type 'SerializedError'.
```

below is updateProgramError when I log is as a whole on the console

```js
{
  "status": 500,
  "data": {
    "status": "error",
    "message": "Something went very wrong!"
  }
}
```

[image]

below is how I have implemented useUpdateProgramMutation().

```js
import { ndovuAPI } from './ndovuAPI';

export const ndovuProgramsAPI = ndovuAPI.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: builder => ({
    getProgramById: builder.query({
      query: (id: string) => `/programs/${id}`,
      providesTags: ['Programs']
    }),
    getAllPrograms: builder.query({
      query: queryParams => ({ url: `/programs/`, params: queryParams }),
      providesTags: ['Programs']
    }),
    registerProgram: builder.mutation({
      query: body => ({
        url: '/programs',
        method: 'POST',
        body
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ['Programs']
    }),
    updateProgram: builder.mutation({
      query: body => ({ url: `/programs/${body.id}`, method: 'PATCH', body }),
      invalidatesTags: ['Programs']
    })
  }),
  overrideExisting: true
});

// Export hooks for usage in functional components
export const { useGetProgramByIdQuery, useGetAllProgramsQuery, useUpdateProgramMutation } = ndovuProgramsAPI;
```

Comment: You've mentioned that you can log `updateProgramError` to the console, can you please add the output of that to your question? Also, checking if `'data' in updateProgramError` might fix this TS error that you're having.

Comment: @DanielBaldi i just made the edit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code as you have it written will not work the way you want. You can't reference the error from the hook inside of an onSubmit handler like that. What you'll want to do is this:

```
const onSubmit = async (values) => {
    try {
         // unwrapping will cause data to resolve, or an error to be thrown, and will narrow the types
        await updateProgram({ 
            ...values,
            id: 'programData.data._id'
        }).unwrap();
    // refetch(); // you should most likely just use tag invalidation here instead of calling refetch
    } catch (error) {
        // error is going to be `unknown` so you'll want to use a typeguard like:
        if (isMyKnownError(error)) { // add a typeguard like this
            enqueueSnackbar('Test message', {
                variant: 'error'
            });
        } else { 
        // You have some other error, handle it differently?
        }
    }
  }
```

References:

- https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/mutations#frequently-used-mutation-hook-return-values

Comment: This worked. unwrap helped me because i had tried to use the try catch block but the error was not being catched. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From what I can infer from this TS error, the type of `updateProgramError` seems like an union of types `'FetchBaseQueryError'`, `'SerializedError'` and possibly other types, which means that TS only assumes that you can safely access this `data` property after ensuring that `data` exists in the object.

In other words, TS does not know which of these types `updateProgramError` will be unless you do some checking to ensure that.

```
if (updateProgramError) {
  enqueueSnackbar('Test message', {
    variant: 'error'
  });
if ('data' in updateProgramError) console.log(updateProgramError.data.message);
}
```

Comment: this worked for the data and now the error is on the message. Meaning I will have a nested if statement to check if message exists on data.

Comment: You could also change your expression to be `if ('data' in updateProgramError && 'message' in updateProgramError.data)`. This is a bit verbose, but unless you have another way of narrowing down the type of your error I don't see another way of doing this :/

Comment: I did exactly that but still getting an error on the second part of the && which is 'message' in updateProgramError.data.

Comment: What kind of error are you having now? I've emulated this in TS's playground and, as long as at least one of these types have these expected properties you should be fine: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBAUwE5LEuBeOBvYc6wCGMArlAFxwCsADDQDR5wAmxhlu++RpFcARMlRJ+jLnAC2CKFEIBzBJX4BlMFJgALAJYQ5cAO4II8AG7IAngdS6AhPyYBfYE+BaAZnAAUAclYxC3nA6iChocABk4XDeUjLyCIHBQmgAdH6EAJRw4NBgADYIKXlgcp7JSGlsKbGyChkA3EA

Comment: This could also be a problem with the way that you're declaring the types of your `useUpdateProgramMutation` hook's result. Can you share how this is being implemented?

Comment: The error i am getting is 'The right-hand side of an 'in' expression must not be a primitive' . I am getting this on 'message' in updateProgramError.data

Comment: I am also getting an error of "Property 'message' does not exist on type 'unknown'." on console.log(updateProgramError.data.message)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239711/discussion-between-dijiflex-and-daniel-baldi).

Comment: Late to the party but this worked for me
`const isError = (result: any): result is { error: FetchBaseQueryError | SerializedError } => !!result.error`